# Providing biometrics for Canada Permanent Residency

Tags: canada, resident-permit

I am an Indian citizen. I have applied for my canadian residence permit under the express entry skilled worker program. I have now been asked to submit biometrics.
However, I am currently travelling out of the country for a month. My question is, can biometrics be provided at ANY country? Or should it only be done in my home country?

Answer (score 2):

According to http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/information/where-to-give-biometrics.asp you can go to any Visa Application Centre worldwide. It does not have to be your country of residence.